# Extracting variable data from p tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How can I extract 249.30 251.50 252.55 246.80 248.20 from below code using python (assuming that the number of digits are variable i.e in place of 249.30 I can have say 2.4 or 2490.30)?

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>
     BSE##B#As on 17 Apr 18 | 16:00@C#7@P#@HL#249.30,251.50,252.55,246.80,248.20,Listed
    </p>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Check out [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it's a package for extracting data from HTML content.

Comment: Yes, I can get p tag text using beautifulsoup and store in this in a list but as I told this list is variable instead of having 249.30 I can have 2.4 or 2490.30. Do I need to use regexp or something.

Comment: If you have a string, you can split based on the commas, with `str.split(',')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BeautifulSoup`.

**Demo:**

```
s = """<html>
    <body>
    <p>
     BSE##B#As on 17 Apr 18 | 16:00@C#7@P#@HL#249.30,251.50,252.55,246.80,248.20,Listed
    </p>
    </body>
   </html>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("p").text)
print(re.findall("\d+\.\d+" ,soup.find("p").text))
```

**Output:**

```
BSE##B#As on 17 Apr 18 | `16:00@C#7@P#@HL#249.30,251.50,252.55,246.80,248.20,Listed`
[u'249.30', u'251.50', u'252.55', u'246.80', u'248.20']
```

Answer (score -1):

The following regex should match those numbers: `(\d+[\.])?\d+`

```
import re

regex = re.compile('(\d+[\.])?\d+')
print(regex.match(content))
```

Comment: You should **not** use regular expressions to parse HTML.  This may be an acceptable solution once the user has the text they need.

Comment: It's not trying to parse the HTML content of the file.  The OP bever said he wanted a parser. It's data extraction. Regex are fine for that.